# Mapping to alternate destination classes based on source

Tags: c#, automapper

Automapper allows you to define a mapping and invoke it with the following syntax:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();
OrderDto dto = Mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```

Is it possible to specify the destination type using a predicate of sorts?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, FooType>().Where(s => s["_type"].ToString() == "Foo");
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, BarType>().Where(s => s["_type"].ToString() == "Bar");
```

Both **FooType** and **BarType** have internal properties corresponding to the values of separate keys within the source types internal dictionary.

In order to map these values correctly I need to be sure they exist, which in this case is determined by the value of the _type key.

**Edit:** If this is possible what would the syntax be for using Mapper.Map<>();?

Comment: If I gave incorrect answer please describe properties to map in  details, maybe I just misunderstood you.

Comment: So assuming you could do this, what would your actual `Mapper.Map` code look like? Would you be looking to map to an object, or a dynamic type, or ..?

Comment: @stuartd Good question - I'm not sure what it would be. In my head I see it working similar to Ninject whereby you can define x amount of mappings for a given source type and then use contextual binding to select the appropriate destination type. Calling Map with the source type only would have it look up the correct destination type automatically based on the preconfigured mappings. It looks like an issue has been raised on the Automapper Github page to allow for discriminators against mappings, not sure if this would help me - https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/258

Answer (score 0):

You may set a map condition for each property, look on these samples:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz >= 0)));
```

and

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, 
                   opt => opt.MapFrom
                   (src => src.Value1.StartsWith("A") ? src.Value1 : src.Value2));
```

Comment: The question is how to determine the type of the target object depending on a property of the source object.